# Chrome popup - what if button labels for "Accept/Cancel" are exchanged?

Tags: chrome, phishing

Almost all websites show inline modal popups in chrome. How can I be sure that "Cancel" is really cancel and "OK/accept/allow" are properly labeled by the website?

Comment: Welcome! I think your question would benefit with more detail. What makes this specific to Google Chrome? I think the term "inline modal popups" is vague as well; do you mean the modal popups shown by Chrome itself or within the website? If the latter, what motivation would the website have to mis-label its own buttons?

Comment: Thanks, Chrome because I expect high security.  Modal Popup means, rest of the website is blurred out till I get rid of the pop-up by clickin on one of the choices. Inline popup means - the popup is inside the same browser window and tab.  Lot of news websites ask questions before you can continue reading. There is no way to tell if popup is from Chrome or the website. A Click allows a website to do things that is not automatically possible to do from javascript, eg. Launch background windows. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are two kinds of inline popups. There are ones generated by and controlled by the website itself, using JavaScript, and ones generated by your browser which cannot be spoofed:

- Popups from a website that are generated entirely in JavaScript are not meant to protect against a malicious website. Such a website could simply not ask for permission before taking an action and simply take it immediately. There is nothing to stop them from switching the labels, but also nothing to stop them from not giving you any popups in the first place.
- There are also popups for various permissions that are internal to the browser. For example, if a website attempts to access your webcam, the browser will open a popup asking you if you would like to permit this access. This popup is not controlled by the website and the labels cannot be switched by it. Unless you grant permission, the webcam interface will be blocked.

Comment: You can end up granting permission to pop up blocker unwittingly .. as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514698/bypass-popup-blocker-on-window-open-when-jquery-event-preventdefault-is-set

Comment: @mosh Isn't that describing a new window popup, as opposed to an inline popup as you specified?

Comment: It is an example of what can be done with a click, but not by javascript alone.